# Upgrading Firebase: "Unable to load your database" Realtime database

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I migrated my projects to the "new" Firebase via google.com. When I try to access my project database, I get only "Unable to load your database." I'm also making an assumption here that the "realtime database" replaces the old Dashboard where I can see data being added or removed from Firebase by my app.

There is no explanation whatsoever beyond the above message. Yet I know there is accessible data there because the listeners in my app continue to respond to it.